# Why do traits in Rust require that no method have any type arguments to be object safe?

Tags: rust, traits

Is this requirement really necessary for object safety or is it just an arbitrary limitation, enacted to make the compiler implementation simpler?

A method with type arguments is just a template for constructing multiple distinct methods with concrete types. It is known at compile time, which variants of the method are used. Therefore, in the context of a program, a typed method has the semantics of a finite collection of non-typed methods.

I would like to see if there are any mistakes in this reasoning.

Comment: "It is known at compile time, which variants of the method are used" - why do you think so? These variants might come from dependencies, at least.

Comment: A small explanation is provided in the [book on object safety](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch17-02-trait-objects.html?highlight=object%20safe#object-safety-is-required-for-trait-objects): _"The same is true of generic type parameters that are filled in with concrete type parameters when the trait is used: the concrete types become part of the type that implements the trait. When the type is forgotten through the use of a trait object, there is no way to know what types to fill in the generic type parameters with."_

Answer (score 3):

I will take this opportunity to present withoutboat's nomenclature of [Handshaking patterns](https://without.boats/blog/handshake-patterns/), a set of ideas to reason about the decomposition of a functionality into two interconnected traits:

> you want any type which implements trait `Alpha` to be composable with any type which implements trait `Omega`…

The example given is for serialization (although other use cases apply): a trait `Serialize` for types the values of which can be serialized (e.g. a data record type); and `Serializer` for types implementing a serialization format (e.g. a JSON serializer).

When the types of both can be statically inferred, designing the traits with the *static handshake* is ideal. The compiler will create only the necessary functions monomorphized against the types `S` needed by the program, while also providing the most room for optimizations.

```rust
trait Serialize {
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: &mut S) -> Result<(), S::Error>
    where S: Serializer;
}

trait Serializer {
    //...
    fn serialize_map_value<S>(&mut self, state: &mut Self::MapState, value: &S)
        -> Result<(), Self::Error>
    where S: Serialize;

    fn serialize_seq_elt<S>(&mut self, state: &mut Self::SeqState, elt: &S)
        -> Result<(), Self::Error>;
    where S: Serialize;
    //...
}
```

However, it is established that these traits cannot do dynamic dispatching. This is because once the concrete type is erased from the receiving type, that trait object is bound to a fixed table of its trait implementation, one entry per method. With this design, the compiler is unable to reason with a method containing type parameters, because it cannot monomorphize over that implementation at compile time.

> A method with type arguments is just a template for constructing multiple distinct methods with concrete types. It is known at compile time, which variants of the method are used. Therefore, in the context of a program, a typed method has the semantics of a finite collection of non-typed methods.

One may be led to think that all trait implementations available are known, and therefore one could revamp the concept of a trait object to create a virtual table with multiple "layers" for a generic method, thus being able to do a form of one-sided monomorphization of that trait object. However, this does not account for two things:

- The number of implementations can be *huge*. Just look, for example, at how many types implement `Read` and `Write` in the standard library. The number of monomorphized implementations that would have to be made present in the binary would be the product of *all known implementations* against the known parameter types of a given call. In the example above, it is particularly unwieldy: serializing dynamic data records to JSON and TOML would mean that there would have to be `Serialize.serialize` method implementations for both JSON and TOML, for each serializable type, regardless of how many of these types are effectively serialized in practice. This without accounting the other side of the handshake.
- This expansion can only be done when all possible implementations are known at compile time, which is not necessarily the case. While not entirely common, it is currently possible for a trait object to be created from a dynamically linked shared object. In this case, there is never a chance to expand the method calls of that trait object against the target compilation item. With this in mind, the virtual function table created by a trait implementation is expected to be independent from the existence of other types and from how it is used.

To conclude: This is a conceptual limitation that actually makes sense when digging deeper. It is definitely not arbitrary or applied lightly. Generic method calls in trait objects is too unlikely to ever be supported, and so consumers should instead rely on employing the right interface design for the task. Thinking of handshake patterns is one possible way to mind-map these designs.

See also:

- [What is the cited problem with using generic type parameters in trait objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57252674)
- [The Rust Programming Language, section 17.2: Object Safety Is Required for Trait Objects](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch17-02-trait-objects.html?highlight=object%20safe#object-safety-is-required-for-trait-objects)